# Is it possible to check if the width of all elements with a certain class equal a certain width? Preferably with Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, width

I've got a page with multiple progress bars, they all have the same class. Is it possible to check with jquery if every single element with this class has a width of 100%? And execute a jquery function when every single element with this class has a width of 100%?

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Depending on the specifics of the use-case, it might be easiest to just search for a progress bar that doesn't have a width of 100%. If none are found, execute the function

Comment: Widths are always returned as `px` values, so you can't check directly for `100%`. You need to compare it to the width of it's parent and check if they're the same, allowing for padding/margin.

Comment: Are these progress bars being updated based on the progress of async javascript functions? If so, it would be better to use promises than checking the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have a working version of the loading divs but this is where I would start...

```
function checkStatus() {

    //how many of these do we have?
    var count = $('.progress-bar').length;
    var total = 0;

    $('.progress-bar').each(function () {

        //save this so we can keep checking it
        var $this = $(this);

        //has it already loaded?
        if (!$this.hasClass('done')) {

            if ($this.width == $this.parent().width) {
                //loaded so add a class and dont check again
                $this.addClass('done');

                total = total + 1;
            }
        }

    });
    if (count == total) {
         //we have finished loading so call function
        }
        else {
            //check again
            checkStatus();
        }
}
```

The idea here is to call a check function which will find each loading div on the page and count how many it finds. Then it tests how wide each is compared to its parent. If its wide enough (i.e. loaded) then it will add +1 to the total. At the end it will check if the number of loading bars is the same as the total of finished, if so call your function, if not check again.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you loop over the all the  `<div>` using jquery and try to get the width attribute that is defined in **%** (as in your case) then you would not be able to access that value in percentage, instead it would always return the value of the `<div>` in **px**, but if you somehow manage to get the values of the widths of `<div>` s in `<input type="hidden">` elements you can get the values from there, and for that you can refer this **demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/t8vSR/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 100%;"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="progress-bar-width-val" id="progress_bar_1" value="100">

<div class="progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 95%;"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="progress-bar-width-val" id="progress_bar_2" value="95">

<div class="progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 90%;"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="progress-bar-width-val" id="progress_bar_3" value="90">

<div class="progress-bar" style="display: none; width: 80%;"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="progress-bar-width-val" id="progress_bar_4" value="80">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.progress-bar-width-val').each(function(index) {
        var width = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(width);
    });
});
```